# Merge Sort based on CLRS textbook

Tags: c, function, pointers, mergesort

The following code is in accordance with the CLRS ([Corman, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein — 'Introduction to Algorithms'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)) textbook which is supposed to do merge sorting.

I am unable to identify the mistake that is happening, although I know there is something wrong happening in the `mergesort()` function. I think `merge()` is functionally intact.

```
/* Merge sort as per CLRS */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int *a,int p,int q,int r){
int n1 = q - p + 1;
int n2 = r - q;
int* l = malloc((n1+1)*sizeof(int));
int* ri = malloc((n2+1)*sizeof(int));
int i,j;
for(i = 0 ; i < n1 ; i++)
    l[i] = a[p+i-1];
for(i = 0 ; i < n2 ; i++)
    ri[i] = a[q+i];
l[n1] = 9999;
ri[n2] = 9999;
i = 0;
j = 0;
int k;
for ( k = p ; k <= r ; k++){
    if( l[i] < ri[j] ){
        a[k] = l[i];
        i++;
    }
    else{
        a[k] = ri[j];
        j++;
    } 
}
}

void mergeSort(int* a,int p,int r){
if( p < r){

    int q = ( p + r ) / 2;
    mergeSort(a,p,q);
    mergeSort(a,p+1,r);
    merge(a,p,q,r);
}

else return;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int a[] = {9,21,4,15,1,3};

mergeSort(a,0,5);

int i;
for( i = 0 ; i < 6 ; i++){
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: So what is the problem here? Does it give you a wrong output?

Comment: The `else return;` in `mergeSort()` is redundant; the function is going to return anyway (and if it executes the `if`, it does do an implicit `return;` after the `else return;`).

Comment: http://xoax.net/comp_sci/crs/algorithms/lessons/Lesson3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void merge(int *a,int p,int q,int r){
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;
    int* l = malloc((n1+1)*sizeof(int));
    int* ri = malloc((n2+1)*sizeof(int));
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n1 ; i++)
        l[i] = a[p+i-1];
    for(i = 0 ; i < n2 ; i++)
        ri[i] = a[q+i];
```

You are writing the elements from index `p-1` through index `q-1` to `l`, and the elements from index `q` through `r-1` to `ri`. If `p == 0`, you access out of bounds.

You want, however, to sort the elements from index `p` through `r`.

```
void merge(int *a,int p,int q,int r){
    int n1 = q - p + 1;
    int n2 = r - q;
    int* l = malloc((n1)*sizeof(int));
    int* ri = malloc((n2)*sizeof(int));
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0 ; i < n1 ; i++)
        l[i] = a[p+i];
    for(i = 0 ; i < n2 ; i++)
        ri[i] = a[q+i+1];
```

Also, you should check whether both indices, `i` and `j` are smaller than the corresponding end index `n1` resp. `n2`, and when one reaches the end of its part, copy the remaining from the other part to the array. The guard value fails terribly if the array contains large entries.

```
while(i < n1 && j < n2) {
    if (ri[j] < l[i]) {
        a[k++] = ri[j++];
    } else {
        a[k++] = l[i++];
    }
}
while(i < n1) {
    a[k++] = l[i++];
}
while(j < n2) {
    a[k++] = ri[j++];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the `mergeSort()` code, you have:

```
int q = ( p + r ) / 2;
mergeSort(a,p,q);
mergeSort(a,p+1,r);
merge(a,p,q,r);
```

I think the second `mergeSort` should be `mergeSort(a, q+1, r);`, shouldn't it?

This is separate from and independent of the [analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14243333/15168) by [Daniel Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011995/daniel-fischer).

---

In `merge()`, you allocate two arrays.  You do not free those arrays.  This is a memory leak.  You should also check the allocations were successful.

Comment: mergeSort(a,p+1,r);  
should be  
mergeSort(a,q+1,r);  
right?

Comment: @VirtuallyReal: I think that's what I said...I quoted the code in the question (because this sort of question has a habit of morphing as the answer(s) trickle in), and suggest that the correct call is what you said.

Comment: Even after correcting 'p+1' to 'q+1', I am not getting the proper output. I guess, I should not attempt to do an inplace sort. Is it the problem?

Comment: @Krishna: I suggest you create a suitable array for `merge()` to work on, such as `int x[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10 };`, and call it: `merge(x, 0, 4, 8);` (I think that's your calling convention), and see what happens.  You can step through it with a debugger.  If that works, try some other arrays: `int x2[] = { 99, 100, 101, 0, 1, 2, 3 };` and make sure they're merged correctly.  When you've ensured that `merge()` works correctly, you can start working on `mergeSort()`.